# CC2 Instance not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I go to launch a new instance (whether it's a new one or from an image), the CC2 instance is not available, no matter what region I have selected. Has anyone else had this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my problem was, if anyone is having the same issue, that you can only launch cc2 instances within a given type of instance. I was trying to make a Ubuntu instance, and that was the reason it didn't work.